# Regenerate wordpress thumbnails proportionally

Tags: wordpress, image, resize

I have a carousel that's populated with featured images, but I want all the featured images to have a max height.

In my functions.php I have:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

In my Settings > Media I have disabled the hard crop function.

None of my featured images seem to respect the 150 x 150 width specified. Even after regenerating. The all appear in the full size that they are uploaded.

Now preferably I want to resize these images to a fixed height (they're in a carousel) and keep the proportions,

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried using a plugin such as http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/ to regenerate the thumbnails. it does say you've tried regenerating but wasn't sure how.

Comment: Yeah I've used that plugin, I just need a way to regenerate all my thumbnails/featured images to have a max-height of 75px and retain their proportions.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size set the new size?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. If I run regenerate now it should resize all the featured images without decreasing the quality?

Comment: it shouldnt reduce the quality, it just remakes the thumbnails and tries to keep a reasonable quality. Ill add an answer and if it works if you could tick it thatd be awesome :)

Answer (score 0):

First try and set a new thumbnail size in your `functions.php` file below the call for the `post-thumbnails`. Something along these lines:

```
set_post_thumbnaul_size(75,75);
```

Then use a plugin such as [Regenerate-Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails) which will re-make the thumbnails to the new size for you.